# pratical example of Postgres regex substring or regexp_matches

Tags: sql, database, regex, postgresql

I have been trying to figure the following for a couple days. Please HELP

PostgreSQL table : locations

```
Id         State

--------------------
1          New York

2          Texas
```

input = 'Greetings from Texas to all Cowboys'

output: row containing Texas

`SELECT id, state FROM locations WHERE state ~* substring(input from state)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.

```
select * from locations where 'Greetings from Texas to all Cowboys' ~ State;
```

2.

```
select * from locations where State = any(string_to_array('Greetings from Texas to all Cowboys',' '));
```

The two methods above both have some problems in some circumstances.But I want to know if they are for you.

3.

```
select * from locations where 'reetings from Texas to all Cowboys' ~* ('\\m' || state || '\\M');
```

The last method would be more better.

Comment: Thanks guys. It works perfectly on a small table. But not on my huge table containing 1 millions locations. I think, it is indexing problem

Thanks for your quick reactions

Comment: If you want this fast for large tables, then you need special indexing and other magic. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/textsearch.html how to do fast, indexed full text search.

Comment: I have discovered why I had a problem. Certain rows of the colunm state has some parenthesis. 

select state from locations where state like '%(%' return colunms with rows

How can escape the () in state

Answer (score 3):

A search word is not a pattern. Try this:

```
select * from locations where 'Hello from Texas!' like '%' || state || '%';
```

or this:

```
select * from locations where 'Hello from Texas!' ~* ('.*' || state || '.*');
```

if you want Posix regexp's.

Example:

```
# create table locations(id integer, state text);
CREATE TABLE
# insert into locations values  (1,'New York'),(2,'Texas') ;
INSERT 0 2
# select * from locations where 'Hello from Texas!' like '%' || state || '%';
 id | state
----+-------
  2 | Texas
(1 row)

# select * from locations where 'Hello from Texas!' ~* ('.*' || state || '.*');
 id | state
----+-------
  2 | Texas
(1 row)

# select * from locations where 'Greetings from you ex' like '%' || state || '%';
 id | state
----+-------
(0 rows)

# select * from locations where 'Greetings from your ex' ~* ('.*' || state || '.*');
 id | state
----+-------
(0 rows)
```

This needs some refinement or course, if you need to detect word boundaries:

```
# select * from locations where 'fakulos greekos metexas' ~* ('.*' || state || '.*');
id | state
----+-------
2 | Texas
```

If you have regex-metacharacters (See the PostgresSQL docs for as list) in your search words, then you might need to quote them first. This look a bit weird but this is what escaping always looks like:

```
select regexp_replace('Dont mess (with) Texas, The Lone *',E'([\(\)\*])',E'\\\\\\1','g');
```

The `([\(\)\*])` is the list of characters you want to escape.

However, if you *never* need regular expressions in your search words, then it might be easier to use a simple string searching function like strpos():

```
select strpos('Dont mess (with) Texas','Texas')>0;
?column?
--------
t

select strpos('Dont mess (with) Texas','Mars')>0;
?column?
--------
f
```

You can use `upper()` if you want case insensitive compares

```
select strpos(upper('Dont mess (with) Texas'),upper('teXas'))>0;
?column?
--------
t
```

Comment: input like 'Greetings from your ex' will return a match for 'Texas'.

Comment: I have also try the Posix but get the following error

ERROR: invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced
SQL state: 2201B

Comment: I've added a the transcript on what I typed in to verify that I'm not telling you bullsh*t. Check your syntax.

Comment: I have discovered why I had a problem. Certain rows of the colunm State has some parenthesis New York (The place to be).  How can I propely escape the () in State

Comment: @Luther, the problem with the strpos approach is that it does not allow to encode word boundaries that means locations such as 'As' will be returned. The approach with regexp_replace works but seems really inefficient in full sql: 

select * from locations where 'fakulos greekos metexas' ~* ('\\m' || 
regexp_replace(state, E'([\(\)\*])', E'\\\\\\1','g') || '\\M');

Comment: @everyone, is it current to escaped brackets and backslash before inserting data in the database?

Comment: If you predominately use the data in its escaped from, yes. Also, if unescape(escape(x))=x then you don't lose any information.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at full text search:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    state 
FROM 
    locations 
WHERE  
    to_tsvector('english', 'Greetings from Texas to all Cowboys') @@ plainto_tsquery('english', state);
```

Standard available as of version 8.3, in older versions you have to install tsearch2 from the contrib.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch.html